# Can't get my footer to work (some text should float right, which it doesn't)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Rails 3.2 and Ruby 4.
I have the following footer:

```
<div class="container">
  <footer class="footer">
    <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
    <p class="pull-left">&copy; <%= Date.current.year %> Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

And the following CSS for this:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.footer p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

I'm basically trying to combine the Bootstrap footer from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/ and http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/.

Problem: Vertically the footer positions as desired. Horizontally what should be floated to the left also positions correctly. The problem is that what should float to the right is positioned *over* the text that is floated left, i.e., "Back to top" floats over the other text.

Minor issue: Also, when I don't add class="footer" in  it doesn't implement the CSS for the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your CSS is making the `p` tags inside the `footer` absolutely positioned. Remove that and it works. Additionally, I would tidy up your CSS by adding these lines to the `footer` tag, this will stop the footer floating off to the right.

```
left: 0;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-right: 50px;
```

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.footer p {
  bottom: 0;
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <footer class="footer">
    <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
    <p class="pull-left">&copy; 2015 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that indeed solves the floating of the text. 
However, the bar with the footer now is not centered anymore. Originally it covered the full width of the screen. It is still that same size but positioned to the right of the screen. So in the browser you need to scroll to the right to see the tect "Back to top".
I also tried it with the code in your message in my project, but with the same result.

Comment: Added some extra CSS to fix that.